# How do I get a list of users not present in a CSV file from /etc/passwd?

Tags: text-processing

I need to compare the user list (`/etc/passwd`) to a .csv file of account and get the account from `/etc/passwd` that are not in my csv file.

`/etc/passwd` shows:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
albert:x:521:521:auto:/home/albert:/bin/bash
alfred:x:521:521:auto:/home/alfred:/bin/bash
```

`.csv` file shows:

```
albert,abc123
```

Expected output is:

```
root
alfred
```

I tried for 2 days with awk and grep but the result are not what I need..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of `grep`, `tr`, `cut` and process substitution:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -xvFf <(tr ',' '\n'  < file.csv)
```

The `cut` command gets the usernames from `/etc/passwd` (the first `:`-delimited field).

Then, the `tr` command converts your CSV fields to one username per line.

The grep command then looks for entire lines (`-x`) which don't match (`-v`) any fixed patterns (`-F`) from a file containing patterns, one per line (`-f`). We use process substitution (`<()`) to use `tr`'s output for these patterns.

Comment: Thanks for that clear and smooth answer. Works like a charm !

Comment: What could I do if I want to keep the same logic, but the expected output is: root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
alfred:x:521:521:auto:/home/alfred:/bin/bash

(I would like to keep the whole line, because I have verification to do with the other information)

Comment: `grep -wvFf <(tr ',' '\n'  < file.csv) /etc/passwd`, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Not as smooth as muru's solution, but another way using `comm`, `tr` and `cut` and `sort`:

```
comm -13 <(<file tr ',' '\n' | sort) <(cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd | sort)
```

- `comm -13 <(<file tr ',' '\n' | sort) <(cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd | sort)`: compares the lines in the output of `<file tr ',' '\n' | sort` and `cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd | sort` and prints only the lines unique to `cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd | sort`;
- `<file tr ',' '\n' | sort`: reads STDIN from `file`, translates commas to newlines and sorts the output file;
- `cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd | sort`: prints the first colon-separated field of each line in `/etc/passwd` and sorts the output file;

---

And another way using `combine` (in the `moreutils` package: `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install moreutils`), which allows to save a couple of `sort` commands (though most likely `combine` sorts the files internally anyway):

```
combine <(cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd) NOT <(<file tr ',' '\n')
```

- `combine <(cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd) NOT <(<file tr ',' '\n')`: compares the lines in the output of `cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd` and `<file tr ',' '\n'` and prints only the lines unique to `cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd`;
- `<file tr ',' '\n'`: reads STDIN from `file` and translates commas to newlines;
- `cut -d ':' -f 1 /etc/passwd`: prints the first colon-separated field of each line in `/etc/passwd`;

Comment: Thanks you !
Also work like a charm and I just learned the 'comm' :)

Comment: ASking the same question I asked to Muru, if I want to output all the line of etc/shadow instead of the cut, how could I do with this command ?

Comment: @Alexander  The solution muru gave you already is actually the best one I can think of, it should take care of almost all edge cases: http://askubuntu.com/questions/735576/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-users-not-present-in-a-csv-file-from-etc-passwd/735586?noredirect=1#comment1092234_735583.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I didn't notice his answer.